# Correct door weatherstripping compression

Tags: weatherstripping

I'm making a jamb for a 36x80" 1 3/4" exterior door, using a common 4 9/16" jamb kit from Home Depot. I need to mortise the jamb for hinges. How wide a gap should I leave for the weatherstripping? The kit comes with kerf-mounted weatherstripping. How much should it be compressed?

[image]

Comment: What are we looking at in this picture and why are we looking at it? It seems quite unrelated to the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was going to say leave a 1/4" for the gap, but truly the cut out for the hinges need to be the same on both the door and the jamb. The door needs to finish flush with the interior side of the jamb. If I see your measurements correctly the gap should be 3/8" since the rabetted jamb is 2 1/8" to the door stop.

Comment: My 2 exterior builder-installed doors aren't mortised equal with the jambs. The doors are about 1/8" proud of the jambs. While a new ThermaTru door is about 1/32" deeper, even though it's the same 1 3/4", same jamb. Its weatherstripping feels like the same thickness. This leaves me wondering if there is some "industry standard" for this gap...

Comment: I'm guessing, a narrower gap seals better, but, when the door warps, a wide gap will allow w.stripping to compress unequally and the door could still latch fine, while a narrow gap would be a problem. So, because the ThermaTru fiberglass door is more stable than those old wood doors, it can have a narrower gap

Comment: I can only talk about what I seen over the years. I have never seen a door not set flush to the face of the jamb, I will say on the hinge side, since warpage, when it does occur will change the way the door sets on the other side. Because doors are made so crappy in these days, the weather stripping is made so it has a huge amount of give and take to account for warpage and crappy installation.